# How to get raw Exception Message without HTML in Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, exception, laravel

I make ajax requests to Laravel backend.

In backend I check request data and throw some exceptions.
Laravel, by default, generate html pages with exception messages.

I want to respond just raw exception message not any html.

`->getMessage()` doesn't work. Laravel, as always, generate html.

What shoud I do?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Laravel 5 you can catch exceptions by editing the `render` method in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`.

If you want to catch exceptions for all AJAX requests you can do this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e) 
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

**This will be applied to ANY exception in AJAX requests.** If your app is sending out an exception of `App\Exceptions\MyOwnException`, you check for that instance instead.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{   
    if ($e instanceof \App\Exceptions\MyOwnException) {
        return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: good.
but how return response with error?
I want to get response through ajax error function.

Comment: @KamilDavudov you mean response with specific HTTP code?

Comment: @KamilDavudov use [the source](https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/ResponseFactory.php#L83) :) Just add the second parameter, e.g. `response()->json($data, 400)`